# How to combine 2 different annotated methods into a pointcut?

Tags: java, annotations, aspectj, aspect, pointcut

I want to annotated 2 different methods and related them together in order to match the global variable and method which uses it

```
  @FirstAnn(funcName = "foo")
  def foo = {
    val value = boo()
    val checkValue = value > 2
    return  checkValue
  }

  @SecondAnn(funcName = "foo", paramName = "value")
  def boo : Double = {
    return B.getValue
  }




@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(firstAnn) && if()")
public static boolean execute(FirstAnn firstAnn){
    return true;
}

@Pointcut("execution(* *(..)) && @annotation(secAnn) && if()")
public static boolean execute2(SecondAnn secAnn){
    return true;
}

@Before("execute(firstAnn) && execute2(secAnn)")
public void before(FirstAnn firstAnn, SecondAnn secAnn, JoinPoint.StaticPart jps,JoinPoint jp){
    if (firstAnn.funcName == secAnn.funcName){
        print("value X is used in funcname Y" ) //here I will retrieve the value from signature  like: value 3 is used in function foo
    }
}
```

But the code doesn't get to this place...Any suggestion to make it work please?
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `&&` implies you expect both methods to be executed at the same time. But of course they are not. Either the first or the second one is matched, they are two different joinpoints, thus combining the pointcuts with `&&` will never make your advice method fire. You need to use `||` instead to match either one.

Looking at your source code, what you probably want is to trigger the advice when `boo` is called from within `foo` and possibly also the other way around. You are also trying to bleed context from the calling method into the called method. This is called a **wormhole pattern**, see also my answers here:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12130175/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/50577287/1082681
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/25075051/1082681

So probably you want to use a pointcut like

```java
execute2(secAnn) && cflow(execute(firstAnn))
```

for your example or the other way around if you have cases where the second method calls the first one:

```java
cflow(execute2(secAnn)) && execute(firstAnn)
```